# Create dictionary of groupings from (position, range) tuples

Tags: dictionary

Given a list of (position, range) tuples, how can I return a dictionary of all positions reachable from a given position.

For example, if the input list is [(0,2),(2,3),(4,1),(8,3)] we should return a dictionary

```
d[0]=[0,2]
d[2]=[0,2,4]
d[4]=4
d[8]=8
```

since, for example, the point at position 2 has range 3 so can reach anything from - 1<x<5 which would cover the points at 0,4 and itself 2.

I coded this by brute force in Python using double for loop but am wondering if it can be done faster?

The positions and ranges are all integers between 1 and 1000

Comment: Please post the code you have so far

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the optimal solution, but it should be faster than the brute force approach. The key is that each index (1-1000) can only have a single tuple, so we can make an array (1-1000) of ranges, then go through that array searching for all indexes within each range.

```
cnt = {} # final dictionary

# test set
lst = [(0,2),(2,3),(4,1),(8,3),(12,6),(17,30),(30,24),(35,5),(40,10),(57,60),(61,23),(75,45)]

# every entry
lstRng = [0]*1000

# entries included in tuple list
lstNonZero = []

for t in lst:  # every tuple
   lstRng[t[0]] = t[1]  # set range in full list
   lstNonZero += [t[0]]  # add to list of used indexes
   cnt[t[0]] = []  # create entry for final dictionary

for i in lstNonZero:   # all indexes that have values
   rng = lstRng[i]   # rng for that index
   cnt[i] = [z for z in lstNonZero if (abs(i-z) <= rng)] # indexes in range
   
print(cnt)
```

Output (formatted)

```
{
   0: [0, 2], 
   2: [0, 2, 4], 
   4: [4], 
   8: [8], 
  12: [8, 12, 17], 
  17: [0, 2, 4, 8, 12, 17, 30, 35, 40], 
  30: [8, 12, 17, 30, 35, 40], 
  35: [30, 35, 40], 
  40: [30, 35, 40], 
  57: [0, 2, 4, 8, 12, 17, 30, 35, 40, 57, 61, 75], 
  61: [40, 57, 61, 75], 
  75: [30, 35, 40, 57, 61, 75]
}
```